# Android Smart Lock Successful banner is only shown when there is only one requested credential

Tags: android, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

Is there a way to enforce Smart Lock successful banner to show when there are more than one requested credential?

[image]

i.e,

```
Credentials.getClient(context)
    .request(credentialRequest)
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if(task.successful) {
            logInWithCredential(...)
            return;
            // for this part, blue banner is shown as normal
        }

        if(task.exception == CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED) {
            // request user to choose credential
            // after a credential is chosen, blue banner is not shown
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that's not possible (I'm the product manager at Google for this API). The intent of the blue bar is to inform the user when their data is retrieved for auto sign-in. When the user picks a credential, they have chosen it and don't need to be informed, so there is no need to show the blue bar.